# How to process a message without message leaving the queue till a condition is met?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

This is regarding a particular use case which I am planning to address via flink streaming.

A message is sent to flink stream processing, the stream is keyed by and thus gets partitioned as expected. However, each message per key needs to evaluated till a condition is met e.g. lets say there is a banking system, where the account transaction (messages) for an account needs to be processed in sequence, and it is not possible to process a message out of sequence as it will lead to an inconsistent system state. The system needs to wait for a message to be processed (maybe even over 2-3 days) before processing the next message in sequence. How this can be achieved in flink without blocking any part of message processing which can be associated with other keys ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the [CEP](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/libs/cep.html#flinkcep-complex-event-processing-for-flink) library? You could specify a pattern like:

```
Pattern<Event, ?> pattern = Pattern.<Event>begin("firstOfSequence").where(new FilterFunction<Event>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5726188262756267490L;

    @Override
    public boolean filter(Event value) throws Exception {
        return value.isFirstOfSequence();
    }
}).followedBy("secondOfSequence").where(new FilterFunction<Event>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5726188262756267490L;

    @Override
    public boolean filter(Event value) throws Exception {
        return value.isSecondOfSequence();
    }
});
```